# Android: Okhttp3: SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to dns/xx.xx.xx.xx (port 443)

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using retrofit with okhttp3 for one of my system app installed in /system/priv-app causes SocketTimeoutException, the same code copied to simple new app and that works fine.

Code:

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(authenticationInterceptor)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .connectTimeout(31, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
```

When the issue occurred ioctl system call  failure is observed

04-06 19:46:19.969 11148 11189 E ion     : ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument

Stack trace

```
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to abc.xyz.com/xx.xx.xx.xx (port 443) from /192.168.43.28 (port 44658) after 31000ms
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
04-06 19:46:51.901  5461  5476 E JavaBinder:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
```

Comment: is this `authenticationInterceptor` is `HttpLoggingInterceptor`? check url you call id ont see any `http` or `https` word

Comment: Hi Iqbal Rizky,That interceptor is used to populate oAuth headders. I tried to log the url in this interceptor to debug and that uses https. I copied this url to device browser and there it is working fine. More over i also tried to add NetworkInterceptor, but call not reaching to network interceptor